# Attach profile fields to created users in Symfony and sfDoctrineGuard plugin

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm trying to attach a `idempresa` field to the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin but can't get it to work. This is the schema.yml (just relevant tables) for those tables:

```
SdrivingEmpresa:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sdriving_empresa
  columns:
    idempresa:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    idlogotipo:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    nombre_empresa:
      type: string(250)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    ruta_emp:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SdrivingLogotipo:
      local: idlogotipo
      foreign: idlogotipo
      type: one
    SdrivingEmisor:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingMaquina:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingOperador:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingTurno:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SfGuardUserProfile:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many

SfGuardUserProfile:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    idempresa:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    SdrivingEmpresa:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: one
```

If I run this:

```
# php symfony doctrine:dql "FROM sfGuardUser u, u.SfGuardUserProfile p"
>> doctrine  executing dql query
```

I get this error:

```
>> DQL: FROM sfGuardUser u, u.SfGuardUserProfile p
>> Unknown relation alias SfGuardUserProfile
```

What I'm doing wrong? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a foreignAlias for sfGuardUser in SfGuardUserProfile entity, like:

```
 relations:
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignAlias: SfGuardUserProfile
```